# How do I add comment to revision entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I want to add comment to my revision entity, but I don't know how to do this, because I don't know how to pass data to either `RevisionListener` or `EntityTrackingRevisionListener`.

My revision entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity
public class RevisionWithComment extends DefaultRevisionEntity {

 private String comment;

/*Normal Hibernate stuff for defining 'comment' as column goes here.*/ 
}
```

I also have entity `Foo` and query which mutates some foos. I would like to be able to add arbitrary comments to the new revisions :

```
public class FooService {

   public void updateFoo( DataForUpdate dataForUpdate, String reasonForChange) {
    //First select and update some foos
    //Now add comment to the new revisions - but how do I do that?
   }

}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a ThreadLocal variable to hold the comment.  the updateFoo method will set it and the RevisionWithComment class will get the value and copy it's current value to the entity.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution but it is rather ugly. Furthermore, I am not sure whether it will work in case of updating many entities.

Comment: The revision listener is a hibernate-managed object, so usually you need to do some static lookup, or use a thread local to pass data. If many entities are updated in a single transaction, this must happen in one thread, so this approach will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with an AOP Introduction. This way you can add a comment field via an Introduction. You can read more about AOP in the official Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html